# Ways to inject malicious content during a HTTP file transfer

Tags: network, http, server, injection, file-access

Assume an Apache server (http, no authentication just hosting static files) is running in my local network which is hosting some zip files. Assume User A is requesting a zip file from the Apache server. Is it possible for User B on the same LAN network to inject contents into the file transfer stream ongoing in the network possibly giving a malicious zip file to User A instead of the intended file?

Comment: Do you just want an arbitrary list or is there a specific concern here?

Comment: i want to know whether any methods other than ARP , DNS poisoning is there any way directly any malicious http traffic which could be injected while the file transfer is going on

Comment: To modify the stream, you need to be in the middle of the stream. To do that without rewiring the network, you need to do ARP or DNS.

Comment: i am new to infosec @schroeder i can get some advice from a pro like u may i know your twitter handle if thats okay

Comment: This is really the only place that I talk about technical security.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is yes, it is possible.

Unencrypted (HTTP) traffic on a LAN can be eavesdropped and/or tampered with, more or less easily depending on your network architecture.

Examples of such attack can be ARP spoofing/poisoning, DNS poisoning is also a way of redirecting traffic from clients to a attacker-controlled server.
Note that the former attack is not possible outside of the LAN network and keep in mind that nowadays, switches and routers can have mitigations techniques to detect and/or prevent such attacks.

The key point here is that since no authentication mechanism is in place, your clients have no way of ensuring that the server they are communicating with is the "real" one.

Comment: want to know whether any methods other than ARP , DNS poisoning is there any way directly any malicious http traffic which could be injected while the file transfer is going on, any reference for exploring deeper about this please suggest